# How to paste PHP code from database to Laravel blade

Tags: php, html, laravel

I have HTML code in the database. I need to paste PHP code into that HTML. The problem is when I try to do it I see nothing instead of code I pasted. I tried `"<?php ?>`" but seems Laravel uses some escaping to avoid any code injections from the database entries. How can I disable it? Or maybe there is some way to get database content without any changes.
Also I tried "`@php @endphp`" and `"{!! !!}}"` but blade.php doesn't handle these constructions and show it as is. I think blade transforms into php rather than Laravel handle blade syntax of pasted content.

Comment: "If you do not want your data to be escaped, you may use the following syntax: {!! $name !!} " - [Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade#displaying-data)

Comment: check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: this is absolutely bad idea , PHP code should NEVER reside in the database!! it is a server language and should never (even if it is possible) be treated as generic content. I suggest you make a deeper study on the PHP project structure before you do move on in your project.

Comment: I don't know what's your goal is but this is not a good idea.

Comment: I know and absolutely agree that this is bad idea. But client wants to be able to paste code.

Answer (score 1):

Storing HTML in the DB is not a good idea. But, if you really want to do it, try this:

```
{!! html_entity_decode($htmlCode) !!}
```